# Connecting to teradata from ubuntu 14.04

Tags: odbc, ubuntu-14.04, teradata, pyodbc

After following the instructions from http://crashthatch.tumblr.com/post/66957708538/teradata-odbc-connection-using-python-on-ubuntu, installed 15.00.05.14 version of teradata odbc version.

```
>>> import pyodbc
>>> pyodbc.pooling = False
>>> pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Teradata};DBCNAME=teradata.xx.xxx.com;UID=myname;PWD=pwd;QUIETMODE=YES;')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Teradata][Unix system error]  110 Socket error - No response received when attempting to connect to the Teradata server (110) (SQLDriverConnect)')


$ odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.2.14
odbcinst: symbol lookup error: odbcinst: undefined symbol: odbcinst_system_file_name

$ python -c "import pyodbc; print pyodbc.version"
3.0.6
```

what should be the workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Teradata machine is reachable via the network.